# Django - Make migration command detects changes but on migrating says 'No migrations to apply'

Tags: django, python-3.x

i am new to django developement after making changes to my model i tried to run the command `python manage.py makemigrations my_app` 
it detects changes in my model and shows me the message 
`todoapp/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model confess
    - Create model UserChoice
    - Create model comment` 
but on executing  `python manage.py migrate my_app`command i've got this message 
`No migrations to apply.`
i usually do this after making changes in models, i don't know what happened now.
plss help me.

Comment: Try this only, `python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, try

```
python manage.py makemigrations my_app
python manage.py migrate
```

If this does not work and the project is still in development:

1. Delete migrations folder and **pycache** folder.
2. Delete db.sqlite3 (your database).
3. Make and apply migrations again.

I think this will work.

Comment: is there any way to solve this issue without losing my data..

Comment: how does it apply to postgresql database?

Answer (score -1):

Delete all migrations files and `__pychache__`except`__init__.py` from your project and app. Also db.sqlite3 database then rerun `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands. It should solve your issue.